# docker-compose not copying files into tmp folder to create container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a container for a Telegram bot running in a docker container which is being built via following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y g++ make binutils cmake libssl-dev libboost-sysstem-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g-dev
WORKDIR /usr/src/tgbot-cpp
COPY include include
COPY src src
COPY CMakeLists.txt ./
RUN cmake .
# ...
```

The Dockerfile is placed in `/home/me/docks/tbot/Dockerfile`.

However, now when I want to organize the files a bit, i.e., put the `include`, `src`, and `CMakeLists.txt` into a subfolder called `containerBuildFiles` (absolute: `home/me/docks/tbot/containerBuildFiles`), I do the following:

- call `docker-compose down`
- edit `Dockerfile`:

```
# ...
 [-] COPY include include
 [-] COPY src src
 [-] COPY CMakeLists.txt ./
 [+] COPY containerBuildFiles ./
# ...
```

- `mkdir containerBuildFiles`
- `mv -t containerBuildFiles include src CMakeLists.txt`
- (just to make sure) `docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm --pull`

Which gives me following output:

```
[...]

Step 5/8 : COPY containerBuildFiles ./
ERROR: Service 'tgbot' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /home/docker/tmp/docker-builder654813864/containerBuildFiles: no such file or directory
```

Now when I'm undoing the changes made in the `Dockerfile` and in the directory structure, everything is working fine again.

I have also tried changing the path in the `Dockerfile` from `containerBuildFiles` to `./containerBuildFiles` resp. `/home/me/docks/tbot/containerBuildFiles` (I know it's bad practice but I wanted to try it) or simply running `docker build . -t tbot_test --no-cache`, same results.

My idea was that maybe the docker-compose context is not being updated correctly. Apparently the files from the docker container are not being copied to the `/home/docker/tmp` folder correctly.

So now my question is: how can I update the docker-compose context so updated folders will be passed to creation of docker containers correctly again?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the directory which the docker-compose.yml sits in (top level project directory) as the compose service will be named after this.  I think I solved a similar issue by doing this, then `docker-compose up` from the new directory.

Comment: @v25 that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing `.dockerignore` file.

[EDIT]
Reason: the `.dockerignore` file included lines which ignore every folder that was not `include`, `src` or the file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
!include
!src
!CMakeLists.txt
```

so they were not copied.